# SEO friendly URL redirecting to 404 Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a sign up page where the user can sign up. After signing up, they'll be redirected to their profile. The redirection is: example.com/profiles/?id=[SOME ID] . This works, but after I changed the URL in .htaccess to be a SEO friendly URL, the user gets redirected to a 404 page error where their profile is not found. In reality their profile does exist when typing in example.com/profiles?id=[SOME ID], but with example.com/profiles/[SOME ID] it says the profile does not exist. Here's my .htaccess

```
        <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profiles/(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /profiles/%1? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^profiles/([^/]+)/?$ /profiles/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
#Remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

        # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

        # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
        # BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
        # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
        # workaround to get the desired effect:
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # Don't compress images
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

The dynamic index file is example.com/profiles/, where the profiles folder has an index.php. index.php are eliminated by using .htaccess. How do I make it so that example.com/profiles/[SOME ID] returns the actual profile and not a 404 error?

Comment: @starkeen It's located in my root folder of my website